# longtable within table environment?

Tags: tables, longtable, threeparttable, threeparttablex

I have several tabulars and a threeparttable that are all included within a table environment (`\begin{table}` precedes them), so they all have common numbering and appear in the tables section at the end of the document.

However, now I have a `longtable` (within a `threeparttablex` environment) and whenever I include within `\begin{table}`, it no longer spans multiple pages. If I take the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` out, it spans multiple pages again but appears in the body of the document and will be referred to as `Table 1` if I reference it.

Does anybody know a way to work around this?

Code is below:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item \textit{Notes:} Param. = parameter, cond. = condition, DC = DeCarlo    (2007), DLK = Dennis, Lee, \& Kinnell (2008), KD = Kinnell \& Dennis (2012), ODK = Osth, Dennis, \& Kinnell (in press), OD = Osth \& Dennis (2013), 1x = once presented, 4x = four times presented.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{l l l l}

%headers
\hline
Param. & Number & Cond. & Datasets \\ \hline \endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{l}{\tablename \thetable{} - continued from previous page}    \\ \hline
Param. & Number & Cond. & Datasets \\ \hline \endhead
& & & \textit{Continued on next page}\endfoot
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

%contents of table
\multirow{8}{1.35cm}{$r_{item}$} & 1 & Words (1 sec.) & DC\\
                             & 2 & Words (3 sec.) & DLK\\
                             & 3 & Fractals 1x & KD Ex 2; ODK Ex 1\\
                             & 4 & Fractals 4x & ODK Ex 1 (Mixed list   cond.)\\
                             & 5 & Faces 1x & KD Ex 3; ODK Ex 2\\
                             & 6 & Faces 4x & ODK Ex 2 (Mixed list cond.)\\
                             & 7 & Scenes 1x & KD Exp 4; ODK Ex 3\\
                             & 8 & Scenes 4x & ODK Ex 3 (Mixed list cond.)\\
\multirow{2}{1.35cm}{$r_{assoc}$} & 1 & Pairs 1x & KD Ex 1; OD\\
                              & 2 & Pairs 4x & OD (Mixed list cond.)\\
\multirow{2}{1.35cm}{$\mu_{ss}$} & 1 & Short delays (3.5 min) & ODK Ex 1, 2, 3; OD\\
                             & 2 & Long delays (8 min) & DLK; KD Ex 1, 2, 3, 4\\
$\sigma_{tt}^2$ & 1 & All & All datasets\\
$\sigma_{ss}^2$ & 2 & All & All datasets\\
\multirow{4}{1.35cm}{$\sigma_{ti}^2$} & 1 & Words & DLK; DC; KD Ex 1; OD \\
                                  & 2 & Fractals & KD Ex 2; ODK Ex 1 \\
                                  & 3 & Faces & KD Ex 3; ODK Ex 2 \\
                                  & 4 & Scenes & KD Ex 4; ODK Ex 3 \\
\multirow{2}{1.35cm}{$\sigma_{su}^2$} & 1 & LF words & DLK; DC \\
                                 & 2 &  HF words & DLK; DC \\
\multirow{4}{1.35cm}{$\beta_{item}$} & 1 & Words & DLK, DC \\
                                 & 2 & Fractals & KD Ex 2; ODK Ex 1\\
                                 & 3 & Faces & KD Ex 3; ODK Ex 2\\
                                 & 4 & Scenes & KD Ex 4; ODK Ex 3\\
$\beta_{assoc}$ & 1 & Pairs & KD Ex 1, OD\\
\multirow{6}{1.5cm}{$\Phi$} & 1-5 & Confidence & DC\\
                        & 6 & & DLK\\
                        & 7 & Fractals & KD Ex 2, ODK Ex 1\\
                        & 8 & Faces & KD Ex 3, ODK Ex 2\\
                        & 9 & Scenes & KD Ex 4, ODK Ex 3\\
                        & 10 & Pairs & KD Ex 1, OD\\

\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `table` environments cannot be split across pages.

Comment: please edit your example to be a complete document that shows the problem, so people can test their answers. A fragment such as this is far less useful.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `table` environment and also the `center` environment; `ThreePartTable` is able to split the `longtable` it contains across pages: it was designed just for adding `threeparttable` functionality to `longtable`.